# Can someone please help me telling me about the following examples I have given a correct answer

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can someone please help me telling me about the following examples I have given a correct answer

**[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqyQY.png):** Let A and B be disjoint sets such that

$n(U)=60,n(A∖B)=13,n(B∖C)=16,n(C∩B)=4,n(C∖A)=22,n(A∩C)=5$

Find the following.

$a) n(A∖(B∪C))=? (\text{my answers 8})$

b) n((A∪B∪C)′)=? (\text{my answers 9})$

$c) n(C∖(A∪B)′)=? (\text{my answers 33}) \text{but I'm not sure}$

$d) n(A∩B)=? <(\text{my answer} \text<{no number}>)$

**[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKXTP.png)** $n(A)=8, n(B), \text{and} A\subset B. \text{Find} n(A\cup B)=? (\text{my answer 26})$

**[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g47Sp.png)**$n(U)=28, n(A)=16, n(B)=18, \text{and} n(A\cup B)'=2. \text{Find} n(A\cap B)=? (\text{my answer 8})$

**[4]**  Find the number of elements of each set if
$a)$ set $A$ has 1 subset: my answer is $A=<no number>$

$b)$ set $B$ has 16 subsets: my answer is $n(B)=4$

$c)$ set $C$ has 32 subsets:  my answer is $n(C)=5$

$d)$ set $D$ has 63 proper subsets: my answer is $n(D)=6$

$e)$ set $E$ has 255 proper subset: my answer is $n(E)=8$

**[5]** Shade the region in each diagram
[image]

$a) (A\cup B)\C$

$b) (A\B)\cap C$

$c)$ [A\cap (B\cup C)](B\cap C)$

$d) (A\cup B)\cap C$

$e) (K\cup L)\ M$

$f) (E\F)\cap D$
My answers is:
[image]

$a), b) yellow; c),d), e), f) is line $

Please help me. Previously, thank you, I believe that someone will find a little time to see a've worked correctly, thank you once again

Comment: a Can anyone confirm, or my solve are correct, or has some incorrect, please